# How to dynamically change the theme in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, xamarin.android, android-theme

I have an application on Xamarin.Android.

I have a button in the application. Clicking this button changes the theme. But I do not want to call the onCreate method when each theme changes.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SetTheme(StaticStore.IsChangeTheme ? Resource.Style.SxTheme : Resource.Style.DesignSx);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonChangeTheme).Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (StaticStore.IsChangeTheme)
            {
                StaticStore.IsChangeTheme = false;
            }
            else
            {
                StaticStore.IsChangeTheme = true;
            }
            Recreate();
        };
    }
```

In the current code, each button is pressed to enter the onCreate method using the Recreate method.

How can I do this dynamically? I don't want the page to be re-created.

Comment: recreation is the only correct way in my knowledge! Why do you need another solution?

Comment: Because it can change the Youtube theme directly, dynamically. I can't do it like youtube with this code.

Comment: That is because YouTube Saves its instances maybe check this for a better explanation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526569/changing-app-theme-without-recreating-activity